# Does Eraserhead have to be continuosly watching someone to erase their quirks?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Sometimes in the anime it would seem Erasehead have to be continuosly watching someone to erase their quirks, because if he stopped watching the target recovered his quirk, but in some of the episodes of the 4th season with Eri and with some of the villains from Overhaul's band it would seem that after watching them once their quirks got erased for a while.

Does Eraserhead have to be continuosly watching someone to erase their quirks?

Comment: U must be talking about the time when sun - eater fighted with 3 people at once. Yeah they had their powers gone for a certain amount of time when eraser left.

Comment: This is why he wears the glasses - to prevent the enemy from knowing which one has lost their powers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As far as I can recall after reading the manga and as mentioned [here](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Erasure),

> Erasure requires a continuous focus on a specific target for its effects to be maintained... Erasure is naturally impractical against groups of surrounding enemies, because it's impossible for Shota to keep watching every potential target within a 360º radius.

This has a drawback as eventually, Aizawa would need to blink every once in a while so the effects are not permanent.

If you can cite which episode you are referring to about Overhaul, please do because I haven't watched the 4th season yet, I only read the manga.

Comment: It also doesn't states if Aizawa closes his eyes, the powers return instantly. It probably has a small cooldown (as seen in Season 4) after he interrupts his focus and before the person recovers his Quirk powers.